# Output a Json Array within a json array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get an output like this one below. Its combining latitude and longitude into an array inside the object. That is what I'm trying to get mine to do. I'm very new to php and json and have been looking it up for days with no luck. Can php output this from mysql database. If it can, how do you do it.

Desired Json output

```
[
    {
        "business_name": "Johns Pizza",
        "latlng": [
            99.457434,
            14.349869
        ],
        "business_id": "1"
    },
        {
        "business_name": "Daves Pizza",
        "latlng": [
            19.457434,
            13.349869
        ],
        "business_id": "2"
    },
       {
        "business_name": "Jakes Pizza",
        "latlng": [
            75.457434,
            12.349869
        ],
        "business_id": "3"
    }
]
```

Current Json Output

```
       [{"business_name":"Crush Wine Bar","latlng":"43.6894658949280400,-116.3533687591552700",
"business_id":"2","distance":"23.0298400562551"},{"business_name":"Apple Headquarters","latlng":"37.3324083200000000,-122.0304781500000000",
"business_id":"3","distance":"23.0298400562551"}]
```

My php file

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['lat']) && isset($_GET['lon'])&& isset($_GET['dist'])) {
    //make a simple database connection
    $db = new mysqli();
    $lat = $_GET['lat'];
    $lon = $_GET['lon'];
    $dist = $_GET['dist'];

    $search_sql = "SELECT business_id, business_name, CONCAT_WS(\",\",business_lat, business_lon) AS latlng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( " . $lat . " ) ) * cos( radians( " . $lon . " ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( " . $lat . " ) ) ) ) AS distance
    FROM business_data HAVING distance < " . $dist . " ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";

    $search_results = $db->query($search_sql);

    if($search_results->num_rows) {
        while ($row = $search_results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $return_data[] = array (
                'business_name' => $row['business_name'],
                'latlng'        => $row['latlng'],
                'business_id'   => $row['business_id'],
                'distance'      => $row['distance']
            );
        } //end while
    } else {
        $return_data[] = array();
    }//end if
} else {
    $return_data[] = array();
}

$bd_json = json_encode($return_data);

$db->close();

echo $bd_json;
?>
```

Comment: I don't know what to put

Comment: Are you just wanting pretty-printing of the JSON output? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Im trying to get the latlong result to be its own array inside the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this something like this:

```
while ($row = $search_results->fetch_assoc())
{
    $return_data[] = array(
                            'business_name' => $row['business_name'],
                            'latlng'        => explode(',', $row['latlng']),
                            'business_id'   => $row['business_id'],
                            'distance'      => $row['distance']
                            );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But the output came out the same.

Comment: @BillyKorsen can i see `var_dump($search_results->fetch_assoc());` and last `var_dump($return_data);` ?

Comment: it actually didn't it removed the duplicates I'll edit the output thank you for that though its much easier to read.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I want to see db result structure and `$return_data` that with my given codes. It shouldnt be same with old.

Comment: You are correct I edited the output in the question to show the new results. I'll also update the php to show your help.

Comment: @BillyKorsen Now its great! What is problem now?

Comment: I'm trying to get the latlong varibles combined as an array inside the array "latlng": [
            19.457434,
            13.349869
        ]

Comment: It combined them but it put both digits in separate quotation marks can the be removed.

Comment: "latlng":["43.6894658949280400","-116.3533687591552700"],

Comment: It is already that format. But when you calling these values, first `0` index and second `2` index. When you run `json_encode` new array, you will see without `array index`

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        
        List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Marker marker = mapB.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .title(jsonObj.getString("business_name"))
                .position(new LatLng(
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(2)
                 ))
            );
            Like this?

Comment: I dont know how to get with JS. Probably with new `for`loop.